# PROMPT_COMMAND not getting executed before going for reboot

Tags: shell

I have a shell script where, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to a function. As far as I knew `PROMPT_COMMAND` will be executed before displaying next prompt pointed by `PS1` (please correct me if i am wrong).

There is a case where my system goes for reboot even before the next prompt shows up, so the `PROMPT_COMMAND` is not getting executed for this case.

I need the function pointed by `PROMPT_COMMAND` to be executed even though the prompt does not shows up, is there anyway I could do that?

My PROMPT_COMMAND records input passed by the user,similar to history

I am new to shell so please help me on this.

Platform: Embedded platform
Code cannot be shared

Comment: What does your `PROMPT_COMMAND` do that is so important it must be run even if the system shuts down before the shell can print the next prompt?

Comment: My PROMPT_COMMAND records history of input commands executed by user.

Comment: You mean like the normal built-in shell history functionality? Doing that at `PROMPT_COMMAND` time is a strange place to do that sort of thing.

Comment: We have app around the normal history called clihistory, we add the command executed by the user using this clihistory. Is there any other way i could do this?

Comment: Can i detect from bash if system goes for reboot?

Comment: Does the normal shell history not just work for you? What does your tool do differently? The problem is you aren't hitting bash again when the system goes down. You are running something which, at some point during its run, triggers an *immediate* shutdown (or so it seems) and you never get back to the shell at all.

Comment: Yeah got that,so can i know the current command being executed from shell?,is there any variable like PROMPT_COMMAND that let us know current command being executed?.If this is possible i will scan for this particular command and record it immediately

Comment: I just think you are going about this all sorts of backwards. If you want process accounting (list of every process that was run) the kernel is a better place for that (and linux can do it for you). If you want a list of all the commands the shell ran the shell has a history function that does that (I don't know when it records it so you might still have "last command" problems on immediate shutdowns though). If you want something else then a better description would help. But trying to shoe-horn this is with existing shell functionality seems a poor choice.

Answer (score 1):

No.

> The value of the variable PROMPT_COMMAND is examined just before Bash prints each primary prompt

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Controlling-the-Prompt

Whatever you're trying to do, you need to find a different way to do it.

Comment: Is there any way i could detect in shell when system goes for reboot,like any variables getting set?

Comment: Nope. The shell will exit when the system goes down. Depending on how it goes down, the shell may not get a chance to exit gracefully.

Comment: OK,can i know the current command being executed from shell?,is there any variable like PROMPT_COMMAND to do this?

Comment: This answer overlooks the `trap` option (which works well for me).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting a shell trap?

```
function my_exit_hook() {
  clilog "Shell exiting"  # Or whatever.
}
trap my_exit_hook EXIT TERM
```

For what it's worth, I maintain an open source command history logger that does something very much like this already.
https://github.com/barabo/advanced-shell-history

You can refer to my specific trap examples here:
https://github.com/barabo/advanced-shell-history/blob/82f9a92650040ed12a6cad511108396fa9a28dbe/shell/common#L86